# FullCalendar display event name only

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

is it possible to only display the event name on the calendar? right now it displays the time and event name. I would like only the event name to be displayed. I know there is a timeFormat function but I don't know how to make it so that time doesn't show. I tried timeFormat : false. That didn't work. It still showed the time AND showed date as well.

Comment: Please post some code or create a fiddle to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `css` as well. Add css `display` property to `none` for `fc-event-time` class.

```
.fc-event-time {
   display : none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just included **fullcalendar.js** and **javascript code invoking full calendar** in js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/JETR/N2vaT/ for reference. Please note the line

> `$(element).find(".fc-event-time").text("");`

which causes the event time to hide - this should be included in ***evenAfterRender*** function in javascript code